# Spring boot tests failing - Unable to read environment variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to build the `spring boot` application as `spring boot` tests are failing. I didn't include any tests. `spring boot` created a test class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. It was working fine when I had db config in `application.properties`. I removed the hardcoded values and added it as environment variables in intelliJ and used place holders eg :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:dbhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/${DB_NAME}
```

I tried using `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` but that didn't work.

The application starts without any exceptions when started from *IntelliJ*. The issue is only when runnning `mvn clean` install the tests are failing.

Exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: dbhost
```

Comment: Why do you define your variables as `key:pair` value as `${DB_HOST:dbhost}` and not like this `${DB_HOST}`?

Comment: @HarryCoder is right. Check `${DB_NAME}` is matched with your postgresql database name?

Comment: can you please display your `environment variables` in question

Comment: dbhost is a place holder value, If environment variables are not given Spring boot  picks up that value

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed by running a .bat file in command prompt. The file sets the env variables. When running mvn clean install in cmd tests passed.